# Alias stopped working after SSHing into Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I am facing a problem with Ubuntu.  Bash aliases like `ll` are not working if I am logging to my system from SSH. It works fine after writing `bash` as a command in the shell.

It used to work. What could be the problem?

```
 echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different sets of files where you can set those aliases depending on whether Bash was started as a login shell or not.

If you log into your machine (i.e. supply username and password), then Bash will always load `/etc/profile`, and load the first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` if it finds one of them.

If you start a new terminal from your machine, you will not start a login shell but a so-called interactive shell. This loads `~/.bashrc`, but none of the others above, and this is also where your alias will probably be stored.*

To load the contents of `.bashrc` when you run a login shell, you should add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Reconnect via SSH, and the alias from `~/.bashrc` will be available.

<sub>* If it's not in this file, there might be other system-wide `bashrc` files such as `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Ubuntu. See: [Environment Variables – Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)</sub>

Comment: @slhhck Thanks some script have over written ~/.bash_profile. NOw I have fixed that.